# Problem uploading code to ESP8266: esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for package header

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I'm trying to upload the example Blink code to my ESP8266 modules, 1 of which is an ESP8266-07, the other a WeMos D1 mini PRO. I've installed the library for the ESPs according to online instructions. I'm uploading from Ubuntu 16.04, Arduino 1.8.9. I've also made sure to use `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

I've tried uploading both through a normal USB cable and through a USB-TTL board, both of which made no difference. My Tools > Board settings are "Generic ESP8266 module" for the ESP8266-07 and "LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 mini Pro" for my mini Pro. In all 4 cases (2 different boards, 2 uploading cables/gateways), I've got the same error message.

```
raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for package header
```

I've also tried uploading the code to my Node MCU, in which case, I got a different error:

```
esptools.FatalError: Invalid head of package (0x46)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've resolved the problems with the ESP8266-07 and D1 mini Pro by changing the upload speed to 115200. 
Another important thing to note is to set the right boards:  "Generic ESP8266 module" for the ESP8266-07 and "LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 mini Pro" for the mini Pro. I sometimes forget to do so when changing between the 2 boards. 
However, I haven't yet resolved the problem where my NodeMCU keeps returning `esptool.FatalError: Invalid head of packet (0x46)`

Comment: What if we need a different upload speed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things to check for troubleshooting:

- Check what your serial devices are enumerating as. They may be showing up as `/dev/ttyACM*` rather than `/dev/ttyUSB0`
- Add your user to the  dialout group

  ```
  sudo usermod -a -G tty yourUserName
  sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName
  ```
- Are you attempting to program through a USB hub? Those sometimes cause strange  power issues that interfere with programming devices. If so, try plugging in directly to a primary USB port.

Comment: I've made sure that its ttyUSB0. Also, I'm plugging it directly into my Laptop's USB ports.